# My function isn't changing text or image sprites in unity 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

```
public void Continue9()
{
    dialogue = true;
    index += 1;
    switch (index)
    {
        case 21:
            conversation1.SetActive(true);
            text1.text = "No... Not farewell";
            image1.sprite = mirage;
            break;
        case 22:
            text1.text = "Whatcha gonna do...";
            image1.sprite = scourge;
            break;
        case 23:
            text1.text = "TRANSFORM";
            image1.sprite = mirage;
            break;
        case 24:
            conversation1.SetActive(false);
            break;
    }
}
```

The text or image won't change even though in the hierarchy index changes to 22. I have checked whether the variables are assigned and if index changes to the certain values

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this method. Debug the program to ensure the switch branch is hit, and make sure no further code changes the text and image back. Also, please add more relevant code.

Comment: Shingo, this is all the code that determines the dialouge for the scene but also when you say the switch brand is hit what do you mean?

Comment: In other words, you need to ensure that the code that modifies the text and image is actually executed.

Comment: Did the convo index set to 21 appear correctly before it advanced to 22? Did you see the text for the mirage? I assume there was no exception triggered in the console. What happens when you step in the function during debugging? Also note, when we say mention debugging the code, it means you need to use the debugger, not spam `Debug.Log()` all over the code :) Just to be clear.